# buildings height data

Tags: data-request, data.gov

I`m working on Communication System Modeling. In order to be more accurate, I want to know urban buildings height or distribution.

Anyone knows where I could find them?

Comment: if you're trying to model a skyline, then heights aren't all you need -- you also need to know the elevation, as some cities are on hills (eg, San Francisco), while others are more bowl-like from being built in swamps (eg, Washington, DC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Street Map has the building heights for many buildings, particularly in the core of large cities. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Simple_3D_buildings#Demo_areas